# Get the column names of a python numpy ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, names

Let's say I have a data file called `data.txt` that looks like:

```
TIME FX FY FZ
0    10 5  6
1    2  4  7
2    5  2  6
...
```

In Python run:

```
import numpy as np

myData = np.genfromtxt("data.txt", names=True)

>>> print myData["TIME"]
[0, 1, 2]
```

The names at the top of my data file will vary, so what I would like to do is find out what the names of my arrays in the data file are. I would like something like:

```
>>> print myData.names
[TIME, F0, F1, F2]
```

I thought about just to read in the data file and get the first line and parse it as a separate operation, but that doesn't seem very efficient or elegant.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Try:

```
myData.dtype.names
```

This will return a tuple of the field names.

```
In [10]: myData.dtype.names
Out[10]: ('TIME', 'FX', 'FY', 'FZ')
```