# Converting pandas dataframe to structured arrays

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `pandas` dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
a = [2.5,3.3]
b = [3.6,3.9]
D = {'A': a, 'B': b}
```

which gives me something like

```
+---+-----+-----+
|   |  A  |  B  |
+---+-----+-----+
| 0 | 2.5 | 3.3 |
| 1 | 3.6 | 3.9 |
+---+-----+-----+
```

I want to convert this dataframe to a structured array like

```
data = np.rec.array([
('A', 2.5),
('A', 3.6),
('B', 3.3),
('B', 3.9),
], dtype = [('Type','|U5'),('Value', '<i8')])
```

I failed to find a way to make this happen since I'm new to pandas. I tried `pd.to_records` but the index is getting in the way and I cannot find a way around that.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Melt the DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) to make `A` and `B` (the column index) into a column. 
To get rid of the numeric index, make this new column the index. Then call `to_records()`:

```
import pandas as pd
a = [2.5,3.3]
b = [3.6,3.9]
D = {'A': a, 'B': b}
df = pd.DataFrame(D)
result = (pd.melt(df, var_name='Type', value_name='Value')
          .set_index('Type').to_records())
print(repr(result))
```

yields

```
rec.array([('A',  2.5), ('A',  3.3), ('B',  3.6), ('B',  3.9)], 
          dtype=[('Type', 'O'), ('Value', '<f8')])
```

---

This is the key step:

```
In [167]: df
Out[167]: 
     A    B
0  2.5  3.6
1  3.3  3.9

In [168]: pd.melt(df)
Out[168]: 
  variable  value
0        A    2.5
1        A    3.3
2        B    3.6
3        B    3.9
```

Once you've melted the DataFrame, `to_records` (basically) returns the desired result:

```
In [169]: pd.melt(df).to_records()
Out[169]: 
rec.array([(0, 'A',  2.5), (1, 'A',  3.3), (2, 'B',  3.6), (3, 'B',  3.9)], 
          dtype=[('index', '<i8'), ('variable', 'O'), ('value', '<f8')])
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot @unutbu!

Answer (score 4):

works for me without melting

*pandas Version: 1.5.2, numpy Version: 1.23.5, python 3.10.4*

```
records = df.to_records(index=False)
data = np.array(records, dtype = records.dtype.descr)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
np.rec.fromrecords(list(zip(df.melt().variable,df.melt().value)))
Out[531]: 
rec.array([('A',  2.5), ('A',  3.3), ('B',  3.6), ('B',  3.9)], 
          dtype=[('f0', '<U1'), ('f1', '<f8')])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can melt and call to_records:

```
pd.melt(df).to_records(index=False)
```

Comment: This returns `np.recarray`, not a structured `np.ndarray`; I've tested this and converting to `np.ndarray` after the fact; Using `pd.melt(df).to_records(index=False).view(np.ndarray)` doesn't seem to lead to the desired result. `df.to_records(index=False).view(np.ndarray)` seems to work, but seems to yield a slightly different type from the other answers.