# Convert data frame to array with column header

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I want to convert a dataframe:

[image]

to array without losing the header column like this:

[image]

I tried values:

[image]

but have no idea how to keep the column header so I can call it for later use. How can I do it using pandas?

```
data = data.values
array([[True, 33],
   [True, 32],
   [True, 31],
   ...,
   [True, 2],
   [True, 0],
   [True, 0]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: The question linked asks for a new column containing the original headers which is quite different to what is asked here. Also, here they ask for a structured array, i.e. a plain ndarray with a structured dtype, there they ask for a recarray, which is a subtype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a way to turn the DataFrame into a structured array, you can find the instructions to do this in the question here [Converting pandas dataframe to structured arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46837472/converting-pandas-dataframe-to-structured-arrays)