# Get the column names of a python numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a csv data file with a header indicating the column names.

```
xy   wz  hi kq
0    10  5  6
1    2   4  7
2    5   2  6
```

I run:

```
X = np.array(pd.read_csv('gbk_X_1.csv').values)
```

I want to get the column names:

```
['xy', 'wz', 'hi', 'kg']
```

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561017/get-the-column-names-of-a-python-numpy-ndarray?rq=1) but the solution provides me with None.

Comment: np.genfromtxt() and names=True option might help. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336234/read-csv-file-to-numpy-array-first-row-as-strings-rest-as-float

Comment: I think you need `pd.read_csv('gbk_X_1.csv').columns.tolist()`

Comment: Is your problem getting the structured array or getting the names out of the structured array? If the latter: `list(x.dtype.fields)`.

Comment: Yes, It is also possible to use: `X = np.genfromtxt('gbk_X_1.csv', dtype=float, delimiter=',', names=True)
print(X.dtype.names)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
import re

f = open('f.csv','r')

alllines = f.readlines()
columns = re.sub(' +',' ',alllines[0]) #delete extra space in one line
columns = columns.strip().split(',') #split using space

print(columns)
```

Assume CSV file is like this:

```
xy   wz  hi kq
0    10  5  6
1    2   4  7
2    5   2  6
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume your csv file looks like

```
xy,wz,hi,kq
0,10,5,6
1,2,4,7
2,5,2,6
```

Then use `pd.read_csv` to dump the file into a dataframe

```
df = pd.read_csv('gbk_X_1.csv')
```

The dataframe now looks like

```
df

   xy  wz  hi  kq
0   0  10   5   6
1   1   2   4   7
2   2   5   2   6
```

It's three main components are the

- **data** which you can access via the `values` attribute

  ```
  df.values

  array([[ 0, 10,  5,  6],
         [ 1,  2,  4,  7],
         [ 2,  5,  2,  6]])
  ```
- **index** which you can access via the `index` attribute

  ```
  df.index

  RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)
  ```
- **columns** which you can access via the `columns` attribute

  ```
  df.columns

  Index(['xy', 'wz', 'hi', 'kq'], dtype='object')
  ```

If you want the columns as a list, use the `to_list` method

```
df.columns.tolist()

['xy', 'wz', 'hi', 'kq']
```