# Change pandas DataFrame to numpy array but keeping column names

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas DataFrame from the sklearn.datasets Boston house price data and am trying to convert this to a numpy array but keeping column names. Here is the code I tried:

```
from sklearn import datasets ## imports datasets from scikit-learn
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = datasets.load_boston() ## loads Boston dataset from datasets library

df = pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns=data.feature_names)
X = df.to_numpy()
print(X.dtype.names)
```

However this returns `None` and therefore column names are not kept. Does anyone understand why?

Thanks

Comment: why do you expect column names should be retained when you access an underlying arrays instead of  a dataframe? You can store the column names as a dictionary/array if you want access to them later

Comment: I assumed the code would create a structured array from the pandas DataFrame. I followed this answer to get there:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561017/get-the-column-names-of-a-python-numpy-ndarray

Comment: @geds133 No, the corresponding method is `to_records`. `to_numpy` doesn't yield a structured array.

Comment: I see, there is a question on Stack that suggests this is the case. I shall comment and ask for correction. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
w = (data.feature_names).reshape(13,1)
X = np.vstack((w.T, data.data))
print (X)
```